# Can't call method from other class (android)

Tags: android

My main class is:

```
package com.myapps.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle; 
//...and all the other imports


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    }

    MoneyCalc moneyCalculator = new MoneyCalc();
    moneyCalculator.MoneyCalculate(this);

}
```

My second class:

```
package com.myapps.myapp;

public class MoneyCalc{

    public void MoneyCalculate(MainActivity activity){
        TextView textview = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.MoneyResult);
        EditText edittext = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.MoneyInput);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.MoneySpinner1);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.MoneySpinner2);
        //...
        }
}
```

The second class is not an activity, I keep it only to have some methods. The MoneyCalc method is called when a button is clicked. I can't read the methods in the MainActivity, it says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "this", delete this token
    - Syntax error on token "MoneyCalculate", Identifier expected after this 
     token
```

The logcat errors:

```
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method MoneyCalculate(View) in the activity class com.myapps.myapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'CalculateButton'
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3584)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MoneyCalculate [class android.view.View]
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3577)
01-24 17:13:31.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I think you want to place the call inside a function and not the class definition.

Comment: Just make sure your `{` have matching `}`. They are mismatching. If you are using Eclipse, press `ctl+a` then `ctl+i`, this might give you insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Put your code inside onCreate and check..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//...

  MoneyCalc moneyCalculator = new MoneyCalc();
  moneyCalculator.MoneyCalculate(this);

}
```

Comment: With this one Eclipse doesn't give errors, but when the button is clicked the app crashes.

Comment: can you post the logcat output for the crash?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    MoneyCalc moneyCalculator = new MoneyCalc();

    {
        moneyCalculator.MoneyCalculate(this);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that is what you want and it is not a good style of coding. Maybe you should move moneyCalculator.MoneyCalculate(this); to onCreate method or somewhere else where activity's content is already set. Now it will compile but wont work )

Comment: Same for the other answer above, Eclipse doesn't give errors, but when the button is clicked the app crashes.

Comment: I told you that it wont work ) if you moved moneyCalculator.MoneyCalculate(this); to onCreate and you call it after setContent method and it still crashes than you have one more error in code you not showing to us.
Post crash report.